# The latest ndk-gdb can not connect to my device

Tags: android-ndk, adb, ndk-gdb

I just get trouble to use ndk-gdb to debug my native application. This is my environment:

- OS X El Captain 10.11.5
- NDK version r12
- SDK version 24
- Build tool version 24.0.0
- Device Nexus 6P with Android N (NPD35K)

The issue:

When I was going to launch `ndk-gdb` it always fail with the message

```
Error: unable to connect to device.
Remote connection closed
```

However, the `gdbserver` instance has already been launched since my app is paused and I could see the `gdbserver` in `adb shell ps` list.

What I have tried:

1. Instead of start `gdbserver` by the `ndk-gdb` script, I launched the
   `gdbserver` manually by `adb run-as` and make sure the `gdbserver`
   keeps running
2. Make a socket forward by `adb forward :5039 localfilesystem:/the_gdb_socket_path`
3. Use `netstat -na | grep 5309` to make sure the port is being listening
4. Use `telnet localhost 5039` to test socket but get the error `Connection closed by foreign host`

Is there any better way to identify where the issue cause the remote gdb failed on connection?

Comment: Could you file a bug at https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to root the phone to fix that connection issue, see:
[Does ndk-gdb work under macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123743/does-ndk-gdb-work-under-macos-sierra)